# Ansible "Failed to resolve hostname inventory_hostname (Name or service not known)"

Tags: ansible, hosts, resolve

I have a hosts file that looks like this:

```
[test]
10.1.1.1     ansible_user=my_username
```

When I try to run an ansible playbook, which calls this test group as hosts:

```
- hosts: test
  gather_facts: no
  connection: local
```

I get the error:

```
fatal: [10.1.1.1]: FAILED! => {"ansible_facts": {"discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python3"}, "changed": false, "msg": "ssh connection failed: ssh connect failed: Failed to resolve hostname inventory_hostname (Name or service not known)"}
```

Does anybody know why it tries to resolve the IP address and how this could be fixed?

Tried creating my own alias as well:
testhost=10.1.1.1

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please edit your question and add the code of your playbook.

Comment: You can try following code to fix your issue

- hosts: 10.1.1.1
  gather_facts: no
  connection: local
  tasks:
    -name: check task
      shell: 'pwd'